# Excel VBA Deleting Rows of Dates

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

I have a column of dates in Column D in the `mm-dd-yyyy` format. Below is the code that I am trying to use to delete the entire row of data if the Active Cell in Column D is either Blank, Today's Date, or older than 8 days (i.e. today is 3/13/14, so it would erase blank entries, today's date, and anything older than 3/5/14).

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Range("D" & lastrow).Select
Do
If (ActiveCell = "" Or ActiveCell = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy") Or ActiveCell < Format(Now -8, "mm/dd/yyyy")) _
Then ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Loop Until ActiveCell = "Completed Date)"
```

If I use the "<" symbol, it erases everything basically, and if I use the ">" symbol, then it doesn't erase the rows with dates in February, etc. Can anyone suggest a method that will work, or why mine isn't?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just thinking off the top of my head, but the moment you use the `Format` keyword in Excel, it probably converts the date to a text value, so you can't perform comparison operations on it...

Try this instead:

```
If (ActiveCell = "" Or (ActiveCell = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")) Or (Cdate(ActiveCell) < (Now -8))) _
```

In effect, rather than changing `NOW()-8` to text, converting `Activecell` to a date you can use for comparison's sake.

Again, I didn't do this with VBA, but I'm guessing it should do the trick.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Try use **DateDiff**:

```
If not isempty(activecell)
If DateDiff("d", Now(), ActiveCell.Value) < -8 then
'do your stuff
endif
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

**Paste the following code into a module:**

```
    Sub ScrubData()

        Dim i As Long
        Dim numRowsWithVal As Long
        Dim myActiveCell As Range
        Dim todaysDate As Date
        Dim cutoffDate As Date


        'Use a custom function to delete all blank rows in column specified
        Call DeleteAllBlankRowsInColumn("D")

        'Use VBA's Date() function to get current date (i.e. 3/13/14)
        todaysDate = Date

        'Set the cutoff date to anything older than 8 days
        cutoffDate = todaysDate - 8


        '***** Loop through all rows and clear values if rows are equal to today's date or older than 8 days ******

            'Count the number of rows with values (subtract one because sheet has headers)
            numRowsWithVal = (Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) - 1

            'Start at Range("D2")
            Set myActiveCell = ActiveSheet.Range("D2")

            For i = 0 To numRowsWithVal - 1

                Select Case True

                    'If value of cell is today's date OR older than 8 days clear the values
                    Case myActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = todaysDate, myActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value <= cutoffDate

                        myActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).ClearContents

                    'Value is valid, do nothing
                    Case Else

                End Select

            Next

        '***********************************************************************************************************

        'Now that values are cleared, delete all blank rows again
        Call DeleteAllBlankRowsInColumn("D")

    End Sub


    Public Function DeleteAllBlankRowsInColumn(ByVal columnLetter As String)

        'Delete all blank rows in column specified (suppress errors just in case there aren't any blank cells)
        On Error Resume Next

            Columns(columnLetter).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

        'Set error handling back to normal
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Function
```

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]